# from module import variable (with importlib)

Tags: python, variables, module, python-importlib

A typical import of a variable `my_variable` contained in python module `my_module` looks like this:

`from my_module import my_variable`

Now, I want to reproduce this exact behavior with importlib.

This means that I do not want to import the whole module, just the variable.

How do I do that?

(Remark: I am not interested in solutions such as:

```
mod = importlib.import_module(my_module)
var = getattr(mod,my_variable)
```

as I do not want to import the whole module).

Thanks!

Comment: To avoid the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), could you please explain why `from my_module import my_variable` doesn't suite your needs?

Comment: Technically speaking, adding `del mod` to your solution (in your remark) would do exactly what you want as python executes the whole module anyway, even when you import only one variable.

Comment: I would tend to say that, for the purpose of this question, which is rather specific,  I use ```importlib.import_module(my_module)``` and not ```from my_module import my_variable``` because ```my_module``` is a string variable that points to a module. 

I would also tend to say that the syntax ```from my_module import my_variable``` is rather common, hence, I would expect that an abstraction library such as importlib would let me reproduce that syntax effortlessly. I can't seem to be able to meet my expectation though.

Comment: I guess I could just stick to del mod as you suggest if not cleaner solution kicks in.